# how to check whether the array of dates is between two dates in mongdb

Tags: mongodb

**bill_from_date= ("2022-04-30T18:30:00.000Z"),**

**bill_to_date = ("2022-10-30T18:30:00.000Z")**

***how to check the array of dates is present between the above two dates***

**check_Dates** =

```
       [("2022-05-06T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-05-13T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-05-20T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-05-27T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-06-03T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-06-17T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-06-24T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-07-01T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-07-08T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-07-15T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-07-22T18:30:00.000Z"), 
        ("2022-07-29T18:30:00.000Z")  
        ]
```

**At mongodb**

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this works for me [Try on playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K4LRr7dNTAL)

```
 "date": {
    $elemMatch: {
      $gt: "2022-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",
      $lt: "2022-10-30T18:30:00.000Z"
    }
  }
})
```